# How can I solve this stream reading problem?

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to read the response from an URL sending JSON body. But my code is not being able to read the complete response. There is a problem in my code but I am not getting that.

```
val url: URL = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
val httpsConnection: HttpsURLConnection = url.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpsURLConnection]
httpsConnection.setRequestMethod("GET")
httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en_US")
val streamReader: InputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpsConnection.getInputStream)
val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader)
val stringBuffer: StringBuffer =new StringBuffer()
while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null){
  stringBuffer.append(bufferedReader.readLine())
}

println(stringBuffer.toString)
```

This above code is not giving me the actual result. 
But if I avoid the regular Java style and use scala source:

```
Source.fromInputStream(httpsConnection.getInputStream,"UTF8").getLines().foreach(println)
```

this gives the actual JSON.

What is the problem in my first section of codes?

Comment: are you not loosing data because you are reading lines in your while loop and not doing anything with them?

Comment: @niekname, I am loosing data in while loop if I check line with null, I  loose data if check bufferedReader.read() != -1  too.

Comment: What is the content of the data you are expecting to get? This is what I am getting when I run your code: " "userId": 1,  "title": "delectus aut autem",}"

Comment: The while loop is wasting the reading of the line. Maybe do something like while (true) { String line = bufferedReader.readLineI(); if (line == null) break; stringBuffer.append(line); }

Comment: @Matthew I am expecting 
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}

Comment: Okay, my answer will give you exactly that but requires external libraries which you should be using for such complex tasks in general. It will eliminate usual caveats that happen in these situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this place:

```
while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null){
  stringBuffer.append(bufferedReader.readLine())
}
```

you're calling `readLine` twice first to check if it's not null, then to append to `stringBuffer`. But actually, the second call gets another line, so you're losing every second line.

The usual way to read buffered stream in Java  is:

```
String line;

while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
   // do your stuff...
}
```

but assignments in Scala returns `Unit` so it won't work.

So maybe using `Stream.continually` would be way to go?

```
Stream
    .continually(bufferedReader.readLine())
    .takeWhile(_ != null)
    .foreach(stringBuffer.append)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you're looking for but data manipulation can be quite complex at times, especially when you involve networks. So in the interest of simplicity I would recommend using external libraries to read a `JSON` file from `URL`.

The following code retrieves your `JSON` file from the link you provided employing methods provided by [JSON.simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1) and [Apache Commons IO](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.6):

```
public void getJson() throws IOException {

    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    String json = IOUtils.toString(url, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

readLine is called twice, and InputStreamReader should use the charset of the source.
Here I took ISO-8859-1 as it will not give an error, as UTF-8 might.
Also readLine drops the line ending, and StringBuilder is faster.

```
val streamReader: InputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpsConnection.getInputStream,
    "ISO-8859-1")
val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader)
val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
while (true) {
  val line = bufferedReader.readLine();
  if (line == null) {
      break;
  }
  stringBuilder.append(line).append("\r\n");
}
```